# jQuery ajax sending data through POST : wrong data is being sent

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

The bit that sends the data out on a button click:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>coformation/appoint/",
    data: {
            "director":director.attr('checked'),
            "shareholder":shareholder.attr('checked'),
            "secretary":secretary.attr('checked'),
            "firstname":firstname.attr('value'),
            "lastname":lastname.attr('value'),
            "birthday":birthday.attr('value'),
            "birthmonth":birthmonth.attr('value'),
            "birthyear":birthyear.attr('value'),
            "occupation":occupation.attr('value'),
            "nationality":nationality.attr('value'),
            "security1":security1.attr('value'),
            "securityletters1":securityletters1.attr('value'),
            "security2":security2.attr('value'),
            "securityletters2":securityletters2.attr('value'),
            "security3":security3.attr('value'),
            "securityletters3":securityletters3.attr('value'),
            "residentialaddress":residentialaddr.text(),
            "serviceaddress":serviceaddr.text()
          },
    success: function(response) { 
            alert(response.message);
    },
    dataType: "json"
});
```

But when i var_dump($_POST) in the target URL, it appears that this procedure sends out only 2 fields:

```
array (size=2)  'residentialaddress' => string 'XXX' (length=34)  'serviceaddress' => string '' (length=0)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Try to look at the POST request in your browser with a debug console (Firebug or Chrome console).

Comment: `.attr('value')` will only return value set in original html and only is `value` attribute is in original html`, will not reflect user input. Use `val()` for form controls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are posting attributes there [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)..please go throu the link to see what attr actually does..

you can even try doing

```
console.log(director.attr('checked'));  //which you 'll notice that this is not you want

 "director":director.attr('checked'),....
```

this send either true or false..

that should be

```
 "director":director.val(),"shareholder":shareholder.val(),....
```

[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) gives you the value of checked element if checkbox or radio .. text if textbox.... i think this is what you want

Answer (score 1):

ofcourse only two of it will be sent:

```
data: {
        "director":director.attr('checked').val(),
        "shareholder":shareholder.attr('checked').val(),
        "secretary":secretary.attr('checked').val(),
        "firstname":firstname.val(),
        "lastname":lastname.val(),
        "birthday":birthday.val(),
        "birthmonth":birthmonth.val(),
        "birthyear":birthyear.val(),
        "occupation":occupation.val(),
        "nationality":nationality.val(),
        "security1":security1.val(),
        "securityletters1":securityletters1.val(),
        "security2":security2.val(),
        "securityletters2":securityletters2.val(),
        "security3":security3.val(),
        "securityletters3":securityletters3.val(),
        "residentialaddress":residentialaddr.text(), //<------it gets the text
        "serviceaddress":serviceaddr.text()          //<------it gets the text
      },
```

Your all other items are just creating objects not sending the values `.val()`, so you should append `.val()` after all others.

Answer (score 0):

if the value of the key in the data object is undefined, it wont be sent
example:

```
data: {
  'first': 'text',
  'second': undefined
}
```

second wont be sent